# Usage of high quality vs high-quality

Tags: grammaticality, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Am I using the correct grammar by not having high quality hyphenated?

> From direct mail, printing & fulfillment, to database analytics and
>   digital media, Company Name continues to deliver high quality services
>   that produce results.

Comment: You are going against common style guides that would have you hyphenate *high quality* when it is used as an adjective. But using a less common *style* doesn't mean that it's actually ungrammatical.

Comment: @JasonBassford If you format that as an answer I'll accept it thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to follow the intended use of English language, then you want to hyphenate in that situation. It's the difference between having a high quality, and being high-quality.